# Comma in amsmath breaks line

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am using the amsmath package to make an equation. But using a comma in the index uses it to split weirdly. Tried a lot to fix allready, but it still breaks. Latex and output can be seen down here.

[image]

[image]

Edit:

If I write the comma without the `$` I get a `Γ`.
Also here is the code of the equation not as a picture.

```
\begin{equation}
   B_i_, _j =
    \begin{cases} 
        1$,$& \text{if } P_i_$,$_j\geq 1\\
        0$,$& \text{otherwise.} 
    \end{cases}  
\end{equation}
```

Comment: remove all the `$` but please always show code as a test document in a text block not as an image we can not test

Comment: what did you want `$,$` to do? It must surely have generated an error

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for the code block. First time posting here will do in the future! 

The `$,$` is so that I dont get a `Γ` in the equation. (Wanted to write it in the question. But don't know why the last line of text is that what it is. I think I accidently copied something over it.

Comment: see my answer, but the main point is that tex points out the errors, you should never use a pdf if you have _any_ error message

Comment: Use `B_{i,j}`, not `B_i_, _j`.

Comment: the question about Γ should be asked as a separate question, with an example that produces the problem,not added as an edit here after the original question has been answered

Answer (score 8):

Never ignore error messages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
B_i_$, $ _j = \begin{cases}
1$, $& \text{if } P_i_$,$_j\geq 1\\
0$, $& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! Double subscript.
l.8 B_i_
        $, $ _j = \begin{cases}
?
```

as you can not have two `_` on the same base.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
B_i$, $ _j = \begin{cases}
1$, $& \text{if } P_i$,$_j\geq 1\\
0$, $& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
l.8 B_i$,
          $ _j = \begin{cases}
?
```

So the display ends at the `$` (Your "weird split")

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
B_i,  _j = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } P_i,_j\geq 1\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

which is error free but incorrect, you want the comma expression in a subscript..

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
B_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } P_{i,j}\geq 1\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

---

In comments you said you use Overleaf, The first code block above produces

[image]

Comment: I am using overleaf and have not overseen the error since the pdf was build. But thanks. 
Only problem is still, that the comma is transformed into a `Γ` for me for some reason. But that probably is because I got a template for my thesis which I should use.

Comment: You must have  big red circle at the top showing an error count, and red error line markers. It is best to use "stop at first error" mode on overleaf [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLChU.png)

Comment: You should make an example of a document which just has a `,` which makes Γ and ask a new question with a test document which reproduces the error

Comment: @Dragonfly see comments above, I forgot to ping you

Comment: @Dragonfly I added a note about Overleaf to the answer

Answer (score 7):

I guess you want something like

*P<sub>i,j</sub>*

so the correct syntax would be

```
P_{i,j}
```

Certainly `$,$` in that context is an error (and I can't think of situations where it would be correct, even if syntactically sound).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
B_{i,j}=
\begin{cases}
i, & \text{if } P_{i,j}=1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]